# Date Between - SQL Server 2008 - ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query

```
WITH NumberedRows AS
(
    SELECT  Serial, 
            DateReceived, 
            DeviceLevel, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateReceived) AS RowNumber
    FROM TBLReadings 
) 
SELECT *
FROM NumberedRows
WHERE RowNumber % 5 = 1 and Serial like '+447584996153'
```

I need to search between date - the last 7 days. I know the search..

```
WHERE DateReceived BETWEEN 'blahblah' and 'blahblah'
```

But what is the function? I have tried different formats to call the date specifically.

The current data retrieves the date in `dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00` format.

I do not know how to use the functions for date in the search correctly (I'm guessing this is why I cannot get any data when I search between dates as I just shows col name and no data)

Comment: Are you planning on passing the date values as parameters to the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using DATEADD function to get data of last seven days:

```
WHERE DateReceived > DATEADD(day,-7, getutcdate())
```

or

```
WHERE DateReceived > DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

If your dates are of `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype, you can simply use:

```
WHERE DateReceived >= '20120601'            --- at or after the 1st of June
  AND DateReceived < '20120608'             --- and before the 8th of June
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Convert function for comparing dates which excludes time comparision.

`Select Convert(varchar(12),GetDate(),112)` this will return date in yyyyMMdd format

So in case of your query it can be `WHERE Convert(varchar(12,DateReceived,112) BETWEEN Convert(varchar(12,DateFrom,112) and Convert(varchar(12,DateTo,112)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on passing the date values as parameters to the query, then you can simply let .NET handle the stripping of the time:

```
WITH NumberedRows AS
(
    SELECT  Serial, 
            DateReceived, 
            DeviceLevel, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DateReceived) AS RowNumber
    FROM TBLReadings 
    Where DateReceived >= @Date1
        And DateReceived < DateAdd(d,8,@Date1)
) 
SELECT *
FROM NumberedRows
WHERE RowNumber % 5 = 1 and Serial like '+447584996153'
```

In your .NET code where you pass the date values, you would simply use the `Date` property of the `DateTime` object to only pass the date portion.:

```
myCommandVar.AddParameterWithValue( myDateVar.Date );
```

Another choice, if you always want to use today's date and you don't want to pass a parameter would be something like so:

```
Where DateReceived >= DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 0 )
        And DateReceived < DateAdd( d, DateDiff( d, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 8 )
```

In this scenario, I'm stripping the time portion from the current date and time by calculating the number of days since date 0 and then adding that number of days to 0. Notice that in the second portion, I started from date 8.

Comment: What is the best way to use parameters? DefaultValue? or?

Comment: @OliverBush - The best way is one that best fits the problem at hand ;). It's hard to answer the question without more details however in general, you don't want use concatenation to build a SQL string in your ASP.NET code. Instead, you will want to your SQL statement to be somewhat static (often a constant) with parameters that you pass into the Command object.

Comment: @OliverBush - If you are asking about how to handle the possibility that DateReceived is null and you want rows where that is true returned, then you would alter the Where statement to be `Where DateReceived Is Null Or ( DateReceived >= @Date And DateReceived < DateAdd(d,8,@Date) )`

Comment: the parameters need to be dynamic so my charts are not dated. As you can tell i am not a .net person. Lamp is my area.

Comment: @OliverBush - The principle of using parametrized queries is the same with LAMP even if the syntax is slightly different. In either SQL Server or MySQL, you can do the date math or you can do it one layer up in ASP.NET or PHP. I.e., another choice in this problem would be to pass two parameters and do the date math in ASP.NET. Is it that you always want to use today's date in query and don't really need a parameter?

Comment: @OliverBush - Which is why I added that if you always want today's date... If you need to pass a parameter, then using a parametrized query is the right solution.

Comment: @OliverBush - That probably warrants a new question.